# EDM Associations are not stored

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Just playing around with entity framework.

Now I have a simple database, containing to Entities

```
Person (Id, Name)
Profession (Id, Designation)
```

which has an association on the Id.

I want to give a person a new profession programatically with this code:

```
using (PersonDataModelContainer dmc = new PersonDataModelContainer())
{
    var pers = new Person() { Id = PersonId };
    dmc.Person.Attach(pers);
    var prof = new Profession() { Id = ProfessionId };
    dmc.Profession.Attach(prof);
    pers.Professions.Add(req);

    var result = dmc.SaveChanges();

    return (result > 0);
};
```

I'm quite new to EF, so it is possibly quite simple.

the effect is: nothing happens and I do not see any
new Association in the associations table.

How can I add a new association from existing entities?

Is there any good documentation on working with that concept?

-edit-
found a copy of the database in the bin\debug folder.
It doesn't contain associations either. but there seems
to be writes to that file each time I fire the update as
in the code above.

Comment: what version of entity framework you're using?

Comment: it is Edmx Version="2.0" on a SQL Server CE Database (sdl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should to use this [SQL Compact, Identity Columns and Entity Framework](http://enigmadomain.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/sql-compact-identity-columns-and-entity-framework/)

```
            using (var con = new PersonDataModelContainer())
            {
                var pers = new Person() { Id = PersonId };

                int pId = 0;
                if (pers.PersonId > 0)
                {
                    pers = con.Persons.FirstOrDefault(c => c.PersonId == pers.PersonId);
                    pId = pers.pId;
                }
                else
                    pId = con.Users.NextId(c => c.PersonId) + 1;

                if (pers.UserId == 0)
                    con.Persons.AddObject(pers);
                con.SaveChanges();
                pId = Persons.PersonId;


                var prof = new Profession() { Id = ProfessionId, PersonId = pId };

                int profId = 0;
                if (prof.PersonId > 0)
                {
                    prof = con.Professions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ProfessionId == prof.ProfessionId);
                    profId = prof.PersonId;
                }
                else
                    profId = con.Professions.NextId(c => c.ProfessionId) + 1;

                if (prof.ProfessionId == 0)
                    con.Professions.AddObject(prof);
                con.SaveChanges();
                prof.ProfessionId = profId;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Have to take a closer look

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
using (PersonDataModelContainer dmc = new PersonDataModelContainer())
{
    var pers = new Person() { Id = PersonId };
    var prof = new Profession() { Id = ProfessionId };
    pers.Professions.Add(prof);

    dmc.Persons.Add(pers);
    var result = dmc.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank your very much! I tried it with dmc.Persons.AddObject, as Add is not available. And I get an UpdateException with "A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = Professions,Constraint name = PK_Professions ]

Comment: the Result is now 0 with that changes, with the code in the question it is 1

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have found the problem:

In the connection string I have |DataPath| which is set to the copy
at runtime.

Setting the DataPath to the actual path at the beginning of the Main function,
everything seems to be fine

This can be achieved with
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\myDB");

where C:\myDB is the path where the sdl file lives.

At the moment I have no idea, what to do about that on deployment, perhaps
it is enough to just comment out that line then, having the deploy path
as database path.